# Autoincrementing field on object save - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

So far, I have this function:

```
def my_number():
    x = '0000'
    return 'MY{0}'.format(str(int(x) + 1).zfill(len(x)))
```

Which I call like this:

```
    number_seq = models.CharField(_("Ref."), unique=True, db_index=True,
                             default=my_number, null=True)
```

It works, but when I try to save a new document, it just creates a new `MY0001`, and it should be incrementing, like `MY0002, MY0003` and so forth.

What might be the reason for that?

Comment: Well, you are using a variable from the local scope you are setting to 0. Why would you expect it to change?

Comment: I tried like =     x = 1
                       return 'MY{0}'.format(str(int(x) + 1).zfill(4))

But it's stuck on MY0002 now, I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 2):

Rather than taking your approach, I think you should declare a `AutoField` as primary key, and maybe have a property method named `number_seq` to get the value for reference. For example:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    your_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    @property
    def number_seq(self):
        return 'MY{0}'.format(str(self.your_pk).zfill(4))
```

But you can't run query against it directly, like `SomeModel.objects.filter(number_seq="MY001")` will not work. But you can do the following to get the needed objects. For example:

```
value = "MY001"
SomeModel.objects.get(pk=int(value[2:]))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, sounds good, but most of my child models will need to have this property now, I don't know if it will be safe with this approach

Comment: Sorry i didn't get what you meant with what kind of safety you are referring to